# NGINX This site can’t be reached

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have a front-end react app, that runs at `localhost:3000`. And a back-end that runs at `localhost:9900`.
I can access my back-end with a postman's(or curl) `localhost:80/api` request.
But I can't access either the site or the server via the web address: `my-1stconnection.lan.test`.
What's the problem?

NGINX config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name my-1stconnection.lan.test;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        }

        location /api {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:9900/;
        }
}
```

Comment: If `my-1stconnection.lan.test` reolves to `127.0.0.1` this should work… have you checked this (e.g. with `nslookup`)?

Comment: No, `my-1stconnection.lan.test` was not resolvedt: `server can't find my-1stconnection.lan.test: NXDOMAIN`. And in the browser I get an error when trying to access `my-1stconnection.lan.test` : This site can’t be reached.

Comment: So where does this name come from? Did you choose it yourself randomly? How do you think it should work then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot one important thing in order to activate the local server:

`127.0.0.1 my-1stconnection.lan.test` into `/etc/hosts`

After this fix, everything started working.